# How to get google access token from refresh token using google java api?

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

How to get new google's access token using refresh token programatically using the google java token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out the following code, and it's the working solution for getting the new access token, and there might be some other alternative for same :-
`TokenResponse response = new GoogleRefreshTokenRequest(httpTransport, jsonFactory, token, clientId, clientSecret).execute();`
 in the code response could be used to generate various google services again and here token is the response token.

Comment: I was searching the whole Internet for this line of code. thank you. it worked.

Comment: I cannot see how this would revoke the access token?

Comment: with new GoogleRefreshTokenRequest(httpTransport, jsonFactory, token, clientId, clientSecret).execute(); you will get new response object which you can use later on

Comment: Yes, this refreshes the token, but how would this revoke (i.e. invalidate) the token? See: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke